# Which plugins come as standard with Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

Where can I find a list of the plugins that will come as standard with a clean install of Jenkins?

Comment: So your telling me all of those plugins are installed by default in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the 'Installed Plugins' tab of the Jenkins Instance under the plugin Manager